# What techniques are suitable for a windows database application where the database is available via http

Tags: .net, c++, database, soap, mfc

I'm starting a database application. The application should connect over http to a mysql database. The application should display the database records table-like. Some dialogs are necessary (reflects a database-record). I'm thinking of a dialog-based MFC application with some functions available via menu and which connects via SOAP to the database. I'm developing on a windows plattform.

Given this scenario, what techniques would you recommend and why?

Some thoughts:

- Is there something like DAO/ADO via SOAP (can't imagine but perhaps there is something like that)
- I have experiences with MFC and C++ but should i still change to .NET and C# because it has built in support for ...

Answer (score 1):

C# .NET will allow you to do that in a matter of minutes.
Using VisualStudio you will able able to setup your database application with no hassles and luckily for you, it will also handle the all-important security issues that usually arise from web-based database access.
By the way, you won't need much C# knowledge to get this done; VisualStudio makes it as simple as dragging and dropping compoments into your Design view. That, and you have a number of webbased tutorials that will make things easier!
Good luck!
EDIT: You might want to take a look at:
http://hackaday.com/2010/09/03/c-sharp-development-101-a-tutorial-series/
and
http://www.robmiles.com/c-yellow-book/

They may help you with your project!